# mapcache_seed - "No space left on device"

Tags: linux, mapcache, debian

### Introduction

I'm trying to seed a cache for a service, that already exists using a second grid.

The error seems to be a problem with the file system, not the seed itself. If I do not create a seed, but request a tile manually I get the exact same error.

### Information on the operating system

- MapCache and the mapcache_seed command are executed on a Debian Stretch Box
- The `INTERNAL_ADDRESS` refers to another local Debian Stretch Box with an out of the Box MapServer installed
- The actual Data of the Map comes from another local Box, that runs PostgreSQL 9.4 / PostGIS on Debian Jessie

MapCache is running on a Debian Stretch Box

### Information on the file system

The system has 60 GB of space mounted on `/mapcachedata`. The space needed for one cached service is about 50 GB. To add another cache I added another 60 GB on `/mapcachedata/cache/karte_sl/UTM32`. I believe the problem might have to do with mapcache not handling this correctly. I inherited the system and tried to add this cache with minimal effort. The old files are stored in `/mapcachedata/cache/karte_sl/GK2`. Creating a few GB of files in `/mapcachedata/cache/karte_sl/UTM32` effected the correct hard drive.

### Error Messages

The command used was `mapcache_seed -c /opt/mapcache/mapcache.xml -t karte_sl -g UTM32`. The console response was:

```
failed to seed tile z0,x0,y0:
failed to create directory /mapcachedata/cache/karte_sl/UTM32/00/000/000/000/000/000/000.jpg: No space left on device

aborting seed as 100.0% of the last 1000 requests failed

failed to seed tile z1,x0,y0:
failed to create directory /mapcachedata/cache/karte_sl/UTM32/01/000/000/000/000/000/000.jpg: No space left on device

aborting seed as 100.0% of the last 1000 requests failed
```

The XML File looks like this: https://www.codepile.net/pile/dZ3z51qP

When I request a tile on via HTTP GET /mapcache/tms/1.0.0/karte_sl@UTM32/4/2/0.jpeg I get pretty much the same response:

```
failed to create directory /mapcachedata/cache/karte_sl/UTM32/04/000/000/000/000/000/000.jpg: No space left on device
```

### Question

Does it have to do with the mounted hard drive, or is there another problem?

Comment: You're using Unix path strings, but don't state the operating system and filesystem format. Note that some filesystem types (and differing creation flags) handle different file layout volumes differently. Early Esri caches flooded the filesystem with tiny files, saturating the *inode* count long before the disk was full.  Others used 64Kb per file, even for empty files, maxing storage with no actual data. Please [Edit] your question to contain more information about the filesystem and the nature of the error, and to ask just one question.

Comment: What do you get from `df` command?

Comment: try `df -ih` to check the inodes

Comment: @Vince Thank you for the response. I updated the question and added a `Information on the operating system` section.

Comment: @mouviciel Theres plenty of space: `/dev/sdb1        59G     46G   11G   83% /mapcachedata
/dev/sdc1        59G     53M   56G    1% /mapcachedata/cache/karte_sl/UTM32N` I tested the creation of files in `/mapcachedata/cache/karte_sl/UTM32N` subdirectories and it was handled as expected

Comment: @IanTurton I think you might have spotted the problem already! `/dev/sdb1        3,8M     3,8M     0  100% /mapcachedata
/dev/sdc1        3,8M       10  3,8M    1% /mapcachedata/cache/karte_sl/UTM32N` obviously the cache created already reached the maximum number of files on **/dev/sdb1** and this might block the creation of files on **/dev/sdc1**.

Comment: Is it trying to update an index or config file on the 1st disk?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Disk Space and Inodes

Even though the space is not entirely used, the inodes were. The `df -i` command revealed the problem:

```
/dev/sda1      2550912   104722 2446190    5% /
/dev/sdb1      3932160  3932160       0  100% /mapcachedata
/dev/sdc1      3932160       10 3932150    1% /mapcachedata/cache/karte_sl/UTM32N
```

#### Solution

I simply deleted the entire content of the **/dev/sdb1** device and everything worked again. I could seed both caches successfully.

Comment: I was put up to the problem by the comment from @ian-turton

Answer (score 0):

As [pointed out by Ian Turton](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/351937/mapcache-seed-no-space-left-on-device#comment576404_351937) and [confirmed by SvenTum](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/352241/115102), the issue was a lack of free inodes.

A possible solution within MapCache is to use [SQLite caches](https://mapserver.org/mapcache/caches.html#sqlite-caches) instead of [disk caches](https://mapserver.org/mapcache/caches.html#disk-caches).

The documentation states:

> SQLite caches have the advantage that they store tiles as blobs inside
>   a single database file, and therefore do not have the disadvantages of
>   disk caches with regards to the number of files stored. As the image
>   blobs are stored contiguously, the block size chosen for the
>   filesystem has no influence on the storage capacity of the volume.
>
> The SQLite based caches are a bit slower than the disk based caches,
>   and may have write-locking issues at seed time if a high number of
>   threads all try to insert new tiles concurrently.